# How do I stop Entity Framework from loading nested objects

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to figure out how to tell Entity Framework how to eager load for a one to many relationship.  Here is an example situation that I am facing. I have two entities:

```
public class A
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public B B { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public ICollection<A> As { get; set; }
    public ICollection<C> Cs { get; set; }
}

public class C
{
   public Guid ID { get; set; }
}
```

If I do `Context.B` properties As and Cs are null which I expect.  If I do `Context.A.Include('B')` property B is populated and Cs is null which I expect and what I want for property As as well but As is populated which I do not want. I want to stop Entity Framework from loading property As. It's like Entity Framework is saying "Ok you want entities A and B and oh look B has As in it so we should populate that too." I don't want that.

Comment: Try making them lists instead of icollections

Comment: Does adding the `virtual` modifier to your `ICollection<T>` properties in `class B` give the desired behaviour?

Comment: Changing them to lists does work but I can't do that because then I couldn't do Context.B.Include("A"). I tried adding virtual and turning off lazy loading globally but it didn't work either

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I have exact same problem.

Comment: No I never was able to find a suitable answer. Can't remember the work around since it was so long ago

Answer (score -2):

You need to enable lazy loading at the context level and mark the property as vritual

```
public class A
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public B B { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<A> As { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<C> Cs { get; set; }
}

public class C
{
   public Guid ID { get; set; }
}

public partial class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext(): base("name=MyConnection")
    {
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Eager loading is the exact opposite of Lazy Loading.